# What To Put as Mailgun Public Server URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, parse-platform, mailgun

I have implemented parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter with my Parse server to send email verifications and reset password emails. Everything is working perfectly fine, but I am concerned about the `publicServerURL` part because as of now I used my `serverURL` for this. So now when an email verification or a reset password email is sent, the link in the email body shows my `serverURL`, which is something I do not want.

So what can I put under `publicServerURL?`? Should I put the URL the projects website or is there another alternative?